# Sign App Bundle none nullsafe Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

I have an old flutter app that is not null-safe, and I can't convert it now, I just want to build signed android app bundle, when I want to use android studio to sign apk I get this error.

[image]

I know I can build it with --no-sound-null-safety using flutter CLI, but I want to upload it to playstore, so I have to sign it.